# Problem with UIKit button with left aligned text and right aligned image

Tags: swift, uikit, uibutton

I wanted to create a dropdown button with the text on the left and the icon all the way to the right and I haven't found a clean way of doing this either with iOS 15's UIButton.Configuration or the classic edge insets (which Xcode warns me are going to be deprecated). What I did is to calculate the padding required to align the button like this, and it works, but the problem is that the layout jumps for a split second when the page loads and when the label of the button is updated.

I considered using a stack view instead of a button, but then I can't get the UIMenu.

Any ideas for how to handle this better?

```
func updateMenuLayout() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        guard var config = eventDurationButton.configuration else { return }
        let titleWidth = eventDurationButton.titleLabel?.intrinsicContentSize.width ?? 0
        let imageWidth = eventDurationButton.imageView?.intrinsicContentSize.width ?? 0
        let buttonWidth = eventDurationButton.frame.width
            
        config.imagePlacement = .trailing
        eventDurationButton.configuration = config
        eventDurationButton.configuration?.imagePadding = buttonWidth - titleWidth - imageWidth - 40
        eventDurationButton.backgroundColor = .calendarText.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    updateMenuLayout()
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should update your question with all relevant code showing the creation of the button including setting the image. The details of the menu aren't important, but all of your button setup code is relevant.

Comment: Hey @HangarRash, the button is created in storyboard so that’s all the code I have for it.

Comment: You state that the problem is that the image jumps around a bit. But in the picture you posted, there is no image. Is that not a problem too?

Comment: That is the icon on the right. And the layout of the entire button moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution.

Start by eliminating your entire `updateMenuLayout` method.

The following solutions assume you have checked both the "Menu Shows as Primary Action" and the "Menu Selection as Primary Action" options for the button in the storyboard.

If your button does not have its own image besides the one added for the menu, and you are trying to get the button title to stay at the left edge of the button, then do the following:

In your storyboard, go to the button settings. Then scroll down in the button settings and under the "Control" section, set the "Horizontal Alignment" to "Left".

Or in code you can add the line:

```
eventDurationButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

to the `viewDidLoad` method.

That should be all you need. This will keep the button title pushed to the left side of the button.

---

If your button has both a title and its own image, in addition to the one added for the menu, and you are trying to get the button title to stay at the left edge of the button and the image to stay next to the menu indicator, then do the following:

In your storyboard, go to the button settings. Ensure the "Image Placement" is set to "Trailing". Ensure "Image Padding" is left blank.

Then the key to the solution is to scroll down in the button settings and under the "Control" section, set the "Horizontal Alignment" to "Fill".

Or in code you can add the line:

```
eventDurationButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
```

to the `viewDidLoad` method.

That should be all you need. This will keep the button title pushed to the left side of the button and the button image pushed up to the menu indicator.

Comment: That is very clever, and it does indeed solve the problem and achieve the desired outcome. Thanks a lot.